# Tutorial for PhoneGap application for Windows 8 phone

Tags: gwt, cordova, windows-phone-8

Is there a possibility to run a gwt web app inside PhoneGap at Windows 8 phone? I found tutorials only for iPhone and Android but don't have a clue how to make this in WP8.

How the gwt web app is bundled with the PhoneGap app so that everything can be installed in one packet to the Windows 8 phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good tutorial is, surprise surprise, on [PhoneGap own site](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_getting-started_windows-phone-8_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Windows%20Phone%208) and after getting Hello World done, just continue coding on www folder. There you can even copy paste your own existing web project output and that way you save much coding effort, when porting app to mobile.